# Landscape layout padding issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My XML layout in portrait is correct, however on my landscape view, some content is hidden behind my action bar.

see example below

[image]

and here is my XML Layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:context="com.example.gharrington.myapplication.NewOrderForm" 

        > 

        <TextView
            android:text="Name:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FieldLabelStyle" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edtName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:hint="Enter Name..." />

        <TextView
            android:text="Meal:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FieldLabelStyle" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spnMeal"
            android:entries="@array/meals"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupMeal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_button_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sandwich"
                android:checked="true"
                android:id="@+id/sandwich"

                /> 

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_button_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Meal"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/meal"

                />

        </RadioGroup>   

        <TextView
            android:text="Drink:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FieldLabelStyle" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spnDrinks"
            android:entries="@array/drinks"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupDrink"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

            >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_button_width"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small"
                android:checked="true"
                android:id="@+id/small"

                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_button_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Regular"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/medium"

                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_button_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/large"

                />

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:text="Notes:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FieldLabelStyle" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/notes"
            android:hint="Notes"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Paid:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FieldLabelStyle" />

        <CheckBox

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/paidcheckBox" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Total:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FieldLabelStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:text="£0.00"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Im pretty sure I should not have to account for the padding at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

for ur linear layout

Answer (score 0):

In your LinearLayout Remove

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

and try it

Comment: Thanks for that this stops the content being hidden behind the action bar, but the content is now on the left of the screen, how would I centre this?

Comment: Have you achieved by M S Gadag solution?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Novarg this is a kind of answer.

Comment: @Karthikeyan an answer should answer the question and also give explanation, not just say "try it"

Comment: @Novarg Ok Thanks. I will keep your word in mind while providing answer next time. :)